# How can I create a portable Vulkan application using CMake on MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, vulkan

I'm following [this tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Introduction) to create a Vulkan application. I've completed it all the way through to the Uniform Buffers chapter and it's fully working on my machine.

What I'm trying to do now is making a portable "package" of the application in order to be able to run it on another machine that **doesn't** have the Vulkan SDK nor glfw installed.

Here's my original CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(VulkanTests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED FATAL_ERROR)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED FATAL_ERROR)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

if (VULKAN_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Found Vulkan. Including and linking...")
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Vulkan::Vulkan glfw)
endif(VULKAN_FOUND)
```

And the expected result after compiling and running:
[image: Window with rotating square]

In order to distribute the application I want to place all the necessary files inside a single folder with the following structure:

- Executable File
- Shaders Folder

  - vert.spv
  - frag.spv
- lib folder (if necessary)

  - libvulkan.1.dylib
  - libglfw.3.dylib

When I try to run it on another machine (with no Vulkan SDK and no glfw), it expectedly isn't able to find the vulkan library nor the glfw3 library.

To fix that issue, I'm trying to use the CMake rpath functionality to link the libraries at runtime, but I'm having trouble doing so.

How can I correctly use the rpath functionality so the application runs on the second machine?

## More Info

Both the development and distribution machines are running **macOS Monterey 12.5**.

VulkanSDK version: 1.3.211.0

GLFW version: 3.3.7

I'm new to CMake and C++. I'm not new to programming

Here are some of the things that I've tried:

## Attempt 1

I tried following [this wiki](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling) and modified my CMakeLists.txt to this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(VulkanTests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(MACOSX_RPATH ON)

set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "./lib/") # Also tried with @loader_path in place of '.'

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH FALSE)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED FATAL_ERROR)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED FATAL_ERROR)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

if (VULKAN_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Found Vulkan. Including and linking...")
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Vulkan::Vulkan glfw)
endif(VULKAN_FOUND)
```

But on the other machine it throws me this error:

```
dyld[2017]: Library not loaded: '@rpath/libvulkan.1.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/user/Downloads/VulkanTestsDist/VulkanTests'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libvulkan.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libvulkan.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libvulkan.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libvulkan.1.dylib' (no such file)
```

### Attempt 2

By setting the CMakeLists.txt to the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(VulkanTests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED FATAL_ERROR)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED FATAL_ERROR)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

if (VULKAN_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Found Vulkan. Including and linking...")
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Vulkan::Vulkan glfw)
endif(VULKAN_FOUND)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/lib")
```

The linker is able to find `libvulkan.1.dylib` inside the dist package's `/lib` folder, however, the glfw is not found:

```
dyld[2069]: Library not loaded: '/usr/local/opt/glfw/lib/libglfw.3.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/user/Downloads/VulkanTestsDist/VulkanTests'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/glfw/lib/libglfw.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libglfw.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libglfw.3.dylib' (no such file)
```

## Edit: Attempt 3

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(VulkanTests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Install)

set(MACOSX_RPATH ON)

set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "@loader_path/../lib/")

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH FALSE)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED FATAL_ERROR)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED FATAL_ERROR)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

if (VULKAN_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Found Vulkan. Including and linking...")
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Vulkan::Vulkan glfw)
endif(VULKAN_FOUND)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION bin)
install(FILES /usr/local/lib/libvulkan.1.3.211.dylib DESTINATION lib RENAME libvulkan.1.dylib)
install(FILES /usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.7/lib/libglfw.3.3.dylib DESTINATION lib RENAME libglfw.3.dylib)
```

Output:

```
dyld[2069]: Library not loaded: '/usr/local/opt/glfw/lib/libglfw.3.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/user/Downloads/VulkanTestsDist/VulkanTests'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/glfw/lib/libglfw.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libglfw.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libglfw.3.dylib' (no such file)
```

### Edit 2: Workaround...?

After searching for a while, it appears that you can compile GLFW from source using CMake. The instructions are [in their website](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html#build_link_cmake_package) under "Link with the right libraries - With CMake and GLFW source".

That way GLFW is present in the install directory and runs just fine... apart from some code-related bugs I'll have to fix :)

Working CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(VulkanTests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Install)

set(MACOSX_RPATH ON)

set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "@loader_path/../lib/")

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH FALSE)

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_subdirectory(deps/glfw-3.3.8)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED FATAL_ERROR)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

if (VULKAN_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Found Vulkan. Including and linking...")
    include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Vulkan::Vulkan glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
endif(VULKAN_FOUND)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION bin)
install(FILES /usr/local/lib/libvulkan.1.3.211.dylib DESTINATION lib RENAME libvulkan.1.dylib)
```

Comment: did you perform a cmake install? `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` only comes into effect when you install, you should then be able to redistribute the application from within your install directory

Comment: I'm using CLion to handle the CMake related stuff. To do that manually I would have to use the command `cmake --install .` inside the cmake build folder, correct?

Comment: yes but some https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html are missing in your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Ok, I've tried to use the install() thing and just like Attempt 2, Vulkan is found but no GLFW. You can see the CMakeLists.txt and respective output in the Attempt 3. It appears to me that the glfw library path is not using the rpath but going straight to the absolute one.

Comment: maybe your libglfw.3.dylib is not a proper relocatable lib (install_name is not `@rpath`), so it has been propagated to your executable. So even if you set LC_RPATH in your executable, the loader won't try to find glfw in this value. You can check with `otool -L VulkanTests`

Comment: The `otool -L VulkanTests` command shows that glfw is from `/usr/local/opt/glfw/lib/libglfw.3.dylib`, so definitely not on @rpath. I think I've found a workaround though. I'll update my answer with the details

Comment: You can use `install_name_tool` to change install_name of a shared lib (you also need to edit executable to add this `@rpath/`, or rebuild). Otherwise, don't you also need to put MoltenVK.dylib somewhere so that vulkan loader can find a suitable ICD?

Comment: @SpacePotatoes I must say I declared victory too early :)... my bad. `install_name_tool` helped a lot. I can now link glfw without needing to compile from source which is a plus. You're right, I had to include MoltenVK, however, the only way I managed to get it to work was by shipping all the Vulkan libraries together with the application since I'm also using some validation layers that must be setup at runtime.

Comment: Another thing that I had to set was a few environment variables that specify where the libraries are in the distribution machine. I'm setting these env variables using the `setenv` call before running any Vulkan-related code.